# Storing data in a set of enum objects

Tags: java

I'm doing a class project about creating an interactive Dictionary. Where you search a word, and the output is the word, part of speech, and definition.

Looks like this.

Search: Reddit
   Reddit [noun]: A place full of memes.

The part I'm stuck on is we have to store the original data in a set of enum objects. "Each keyword, each part of speech, and each definition must be stored in a separate data field".

Does that mean I have to store all the keywords in enum, all the part of speech in an enum and all the definitons in a separate enum in the same class? What does it mean by "separate data field".

Comment: The only thing that should be stored as an enum are the unchanging sections -- the parts of speech: noun, verb, adverb, ... All the rest should most definitely *not* be enum. The keywords, such as Reddit, should *not* be an enum as that is data, data that is not constant and might change

Comment: Well an enum is a class. as such it can have a constructor and fields. Thats one posibility that might make sense. But I guess only your teacher can clarify the task. What I realy can't make any sense of is "set of enums" and "keywords" together - well: teacher.

Comment: by "separate data fields" "he" means "(dfferent type) object variables" ;)

Comment: ...and after compiling a (java) enum, their count & all properties are *fixed*.

Comment: Sure, and odd as it can possibly be - at least a remote chance to fullfill "we have to store the original data in a set of enum objects". Makes all little sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of going about it:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {

    HashMap<String, Word> dictionary = new HashMap<String, Word>();

}

class Word{

    private String word;
    private WordType type;
    private String definition;

    public Word(String word, WordType type, String definition) {
        this.setWord(word);
        this.setType(type);
        this.setDefinition(definition);
    }

    public String getDefinition() {
        return definition;
    }

    public void setDefinition(String definition) {
        this.definition = definition;
    }

    public WordType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(WordType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

}

enum WordType{

    Noun, 
    Verb,
    etc;

}
```

This is one way to implement a 'Word' into your dictionary project. With a `toString()` override in your Word class and some file IO you should be good to go.

Comment: First of all thank you for the help!! I wanna note, that yes I have to store the original data in a set of enum objects and to re-emphasize that I have to store each keyword, each part of speech, and each definition in a separate data field. And I have to use data structures to store the dictionary's data. Which is what i'm so confused on.

Comment: No problem! I guess I don't really understand the question. Does the word, part of speech, and definition all have to be enums? The storing of the data won't be hard if you're allowed to use Strings. In my example, I used a HashMap, which you can access in constant time, to bind my Word objects to their corresponding String word.

Comment: Well thats a good question. There are four criterias, Data Source, Data Structure, Data Loading, and User Interface. So when the program takes an input from the user, the program searches the dictionaries data, and not the data source. So for the Data Source, you store the data in a set of enum objects(which is puzzling to me). Each keyword, each part of speech, and each definition stored in a data field. It also says "Do not to combine them such as storing three parts in one String".

Comment: I'm just as puzzled as you, my friend. From what I've read it seems like you're supposed to store the word, which is an enum and get data by using that enum. Does this fit the criteria `HashMap<WordName, Word> dictionary`? I'm assuming you already have the words you're supposed to have in this dictionary? I don't think there is a way to parse an enum at runtime in Java without reflection (and maybe not even then).

Comment: @JustForLong After re-reading your post I see that you are saying data fields. Fields are simply variables within the class. These can be objects, primitive types, or enums. Unless it specifically tells you to, I don't think you will need enums. My example may work as is if our definitons of field are the same.

Comment: Ya we have the words, part of speech and definition.  Okay I'm understanding pieces of it so far. Last question I have is, what does it mean when the assignment says, "When our program starts, it loads all the original data from the Data Source into our dictionary data structure. Data loading must finish before our program starts interacting with users. "

Comment: @JustForLong You need to read the data from a file and load it into your HashMap. I would suggest having a file called dictionarywords.dat and putting the words in this format: `Word PartOfSpeech Definition` and read it through a scanner while adding the words to the HashMap until no lines are left.

Comment: interesting, I'll research and implement that. You've helped me jump mental hurdles through this assignment. Thank you :)

Comment: Happy to help :)